# Core data app is crashing while perform fetch request

Tags: iphone

I am fetching result from core data entity

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Set up the fetched results controller.

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tutorial" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];


    //sorting 
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    //release here
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

My app is crashing while perform fetch

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //title


    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    //add song button



    UIBarButtonItem *addSongbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Songs" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addSongs)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addSongbutton;

    [addSongbutton release];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [(SongsWithLyricsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
    }

    self.title = @"Song List";

    //Error message
    NSError *error =nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultController]performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        abort();

    }




}
```

this is Nslog output
Unresolved error (null), (null)
please help

Comment: well, the crash is because of the abort() :-).

Comment: ok.. but.. it is not loading records why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grrr ... always push return in a comment ... I wanted to add that an error output of (null) (null) looks to me as if there is no error, but then the fetch shouldn't return false.

Are you sure fetchedResultsController is not nil when you try to call performFetch on it?

Comment: hmmm ... now I see that you call [self fetchedResultController ...], but the getter function you defined is called fetchedResultsController (with an "s") - so the getter function is never called. You should name your global NSFetchedResultsController variable the same as the getter function, with the "s". See also http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that your implementation of `setFetchedResultsController` has a bug?